# Dual norm confusion

Tags: vector-spaces

The dual norm is defined as follows, given we are dealing with vector spaces:

$||z||_* = sup\{z^Tx \space|\space ||x||\le 1\}$

$z\in V^*, x\in V$

$z:x\mapsto \mathbb{R}$

I interpret this as the least upper bound of the set of the product of linear functionals $z^T$ in the dual space $V^*$ with the elements of the vector space $V$

Hence, it is whichever $z^T x$ combination that gives the largest scalar, given that each vector has one functional associated with it

In a finite element book, the dual norm is given as follows:

$||z||_* = sup_z \frac{z^T x}{||z||}$

In this case, are we taking the supremum of a particular functional (i.e. the infinity norm on the linear vector $z^T$), or is it implicit that the supremum is being taken over the set of functionals $z^T$?

Comment: That looks like a typo, z and x right next to each other and swapped.

Answer (score 0):

(1). With regard to your last sentence the formula for $\|z\|_*$ should be $$ \|z\|_*=\sup \;\{ \frac {|z^Tx|}{\|x\|}: 0\ne x\in V \}.$$

(2). Let $f:V\to S$ be linear (where $S= \mathbb R$ or $S=\mathbb C$).

We have $\{x\in V:\|x\|=1\}=\{y/\|y\|:0\ne y\in V\}.$

Therefore  $$\sup\;\{|f(x)|:x\in V\land \|x\|=1\}=$$ $$=\sup \;\{|f(y/\|y\|):0\ne y\in V\}=$$ $$=\sup \;\{|f(y)|/\|y\|\}: 0\ne y\in V\}.$$ So the two definitions. of $\|f\|$ are equivalent.

The intuition is that $\|f\|$ is the sharpest upper limit on how "big" $f(x)$ can be compared to $x$.

Comment: Ok that makes sense somewhat. The x vector is normalised to determine the size of f(x). The dual norm is the supremum of the set of all reals (or complex numbers) obtained from the scalar set of mappings z^T(x)/||x|| and the book has omitted the set notation. Hence, if I had V = { (1,1), (2,1), (3,1)} and Z^T = { (1,1)^T, (2,1)^T, (1,2)^T } then the supremum would be the least upper bound of { 2, 5, 5} = 5